# Define methods for subclasses of type classes

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I tried this:

```
class Functor f where
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
class (Functor f) => Applicative f where
    pure  :: a -> f a
    (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
    fmap f x = pure f <*> x
```

I got this:

```
`fmap' is not a (visible) method of class `Applicative'
```

How to define `fmap` for `Applicative` and other subclasses of `Functor`?

Comment: `(<$>)` already does, it is the infix version of `fmap`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you're asking for isn't (yet) implemented for Haskell. However, there is a proposal for such a feature called [Default Superclass Instances](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/DefaultSuperclassInstances#Theproposal), which would allow you to do declare:

```
class Functor f => Applicative f where
  return :: x -> f x
  (<*>) :: f (s -> t) -> f s -> f t

  instance Functor f where
    fmap = (<*>) . pure
```

Answer (score 9):

You are understanding this wrong: there are no subclasses concept playing anywhere.

When there is a class constraint like this: `class (Functor f) => Applicative f`, it means that for defining some type to be an `Applicative` instance, it should be *already* an instance of `Functor`.

Consider the datatype `Maybe`:

You define its `Functor` instance like this:

```
instance  Functor Maybe  where
    fmap _ Nothing       = Nothing
    fmap f (Just a)      = Just (f a)
```

and its `Applicative` instance like this:

```
instance Applicative Maybe where
   pure = Just
   (Just f) <*> (Just x) = Just (f x)
   _        <*> _        = Nothing
```

As seen in the example above, you cannot define new function named `fmap` in `Applicative` instance just because it has its class constraint. The class constraint just tells you that `Applicative` instance should already be an instance of `Functor` typeclass. You have to define `fmap` function while creating `Functor` instance, because that's what the `Functor` typeclass needs but not the `Applicative` one.

Also, your typeclass should look like this:

```
class Functor f where
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

class (Functor f) => Applicative f where
    pure  :: a -> f a
    (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

You don't need to put `fmap` additionally into the `Applicative` typeclass also. The class constraint implies that all types having `Applicative` need to have `fmap` defined.

Comment: So that is what inheritance means.

Comment: @ThePiercingPrince I have updated with explanation. It is better if you don't try to find analogy between OOP languages inheritance and Haskell.